# could not deserialize; nested exception is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity where one of its members is a User-defined type which is not serialized. When I tried to hit the database to extract the data from the table I am getting below exception.

**could not deserialize; nested exception is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize**

```
@Entity
public class MyTable implements Serializable {

private Long id;
private String name;
private UserDefinedType a;

}
```

This UserDefinedType is from a 3rd party library which can't be updated, Is there any way we can solve this without changing the type of member a;

I am using Spring Data JPA to achieve this.

Comment: For database add `@Transient` to `private UserDefinedType a;` for web applications change to `private transient UserDefinedType a;`

Comment: Adding these wont carry any information, here this object will contain information that should carry from database to UI

Comment: If you need the fields of `UserDefinedType`, but they can't be serialized, you need to manually map them in your `MyTable` entity

Comment: Can you help me with some references, As I am unable to get what you are trying to explain